# Derivation of acceleration and tension of pulley system

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, forces, free-body-diagram, string

On [this website](http://farside.ph.utexas.edu/teaching/301/lectures/node48.html) I am considering the question that goes along with figure 30. I am going to assume downwards is negative and rightwards is positive (not to confuse upwards as the website says).

The net forces on the object with mass $m_1$:
$$\sum{\vec{F}}=T+m_1g-m_1g=T$$
The net forces on the object with mass $m_2$:
$$\sum{\vec{F}}=T-m_2g$$

Using Newton's Second Law:
$$T=m_1a$$
$$T-m_2g=m_2a$$

Solving for $T$ and $a$ as the website does I get:
$$a=g\left(\frac{m_2}{m_1-m_2}\right)$$
$$T=g\left(\frac{m_1m_2}{m_1-m_2}\right)$$

My question is are these equations correct as the result of changing the signs of the directions? Or should I make all forces positive as done on the website?

Comment: This arrangement is sometimes called a "half-Atwood's machine" and similar names.

Comment: No! You should choose down as positive so that the positive acceleration of $m_1$ is coordinated with the positive acceleration with $m_2$. if you are going to use the same letter $a$ for both accelerations. Otherwise, use $a_1$ and $a_2$ with $a_1=-a_2$.

Comment: @BillN Isn’t that what I did on my answer? Or am I misinterpreting something?

Comment: If to the right is positive for $m_1$, and the string stays tight, then down must be positive for $m_2$ if you use the same variable letter for the acceleration of both masses.  The N2L equation should be $m_2 g - T = m_2 a.$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have realized that I must set
$$T-m_2g=-m_2a$$
because of my sign changes and then the equations work out.